# Drupal 6: How to create a view which displays all articles written by all members of a group

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I want to create a view which displays all articles written by all members of that group. How to accomplish this in drupal 6?

Answer (score 0):

Add filters to view.

[image]

1) User: Roles / Is one of / Select group of members

2) Node: Type (if you need to specify content type)